# cannot launch node of type interactive_marker_twist_server

Tags: ros, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS-Kinetic under Ubuntu 16.06. I am constantly seeing this error in my screen.

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [interactive_marker_twist_server/marker_server]: interactive_marker_twist_server
```

I have gone through this [Link](http://wiki.ros.org/interactive_marker_twist_server) and it shows this package is available for indigo and jade only. I tried but it does not work with Kinetic. I don't want to develop my expertise for indigo. Please, help. Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244645/cannot-launch-node-of-type--interactive_marker_twist_server/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If a package is not available for a particular ROS release, you can always try to build from source.

For `interactive_marker_twist_server` specifically (but the process is the same for others):

```
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/ros-visualization/interactive_marker_twist_server.git
rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
cd /path/to/your/catkin_ws
catkin_make
source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Provided that all dependencies of the package are available (`rosdep` succeeds) and compilation was successful, you should now be able to use the package.

> I don't want to develop my expertise for indigo.

There really isn't that much difference (anymore) between ROS versions, so you should be fine on either.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-10-20**:
Thank you gvdhoorn :)

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2017-05-12**:
It appears that this package is now available for Kinetic. I did `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-interactive-marker-twist-server` and it installed without issue.